# How do I concatenate groups of 3 columns into one in a large pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have:

```
    0 1 2   0 1 2     0     1      2        ...
0 | a c e | r t v | alpha gamma   epsilon   ...
1 | b d f | s u w | beta  delta   zeta      ...
```

And I want to retrieve:

```
    0   1     2     ...
0 | a | r | alpha   ...
1 | b | s | beta    ...
2 | c | t | gamma   ...
3 | d | u | delta   ...
4 | e | v | epsilon ...
5 | f | w | zeta    ...
```

My DataFrames are way larger than this, so a general solution would be much appreciated. For example, if I have 300 columns with 10000 rows each, I'd like to retrieve 100 columns with 30000 rows each. 
The files are generated through Fortran code, which by default groups them in sets of 3 columns. I'm currently reading them with:

```
    pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=0, 
               engine='c', dtype=np.float64, low_memory=False) 
               for file in list_glob), axis='columns')
```

Thanks!

Comment: probably better to know how u read it in, usually pandas would give different numbers for d columns

Comment: Thanks. I've uploaded the question for more clarity.

Comment: hmmm. ok, do u mind running ```df.to_dict("records")``` . could help in reading in the data

Comment: i don't understand how you get that output with `sep='\s+'` is | a delimiter ? why not do `pd.read_csv(..sep='|')`

Comment: @sammywemmy It prompts a warning: "UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted." But if I do it anyways, translating to the example above (and with .head(2)), the results yield: 
[{0: a, 1: c, 2: e}, {0: b, 1: d, 2: f}] . Is this useful or do you need more clarification?

Comment: @Datanovice I don 't get any " | ", I just added them manually here in order to distinguish a group inside the DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try numpy's `reshape` and `transpose`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(len(df),3,-1)
               .transpose(2,0,1)
               .reshape(3*len(df),-1)
            )
```

Output:

```
   0  1        2
0  a  r    alpha
1  b  s     beta
2  c  t    gamma
3  d  u    delta
4  e  v  epsilon
5  f  w     zeta
```

You can manipulate the data read from `read_csv` before concatenation:

```
pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=0, 
                       engine='c', dtype=np.float64, low_memory=False)
             .melt()[['value']]                    # turn each dataframe into single-column one
           for file in list_glob), axis='columns')
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I like your second solution, with melt() after the read_csv. It's more elegant and uses less code. Also thanks to @sammywemmy for prompting the idea for me to show how I'm reading the files.

Comment: On a side note, is there an optimal way to deal with data this large? I'm currently taking 10+ seconds just to load in 3 files with 100000 data entries each... And ideally I'd work with way more than 3 files, I'm just running tests

Comment: I’m not sure. Usually, it shouldn’t take that long to read 100k lines. I used to read millions of lines in just couple of seconds.

Comment: It's strange indeed, I'm on a maxed out MacBook Pro 2019. Maybe it's the concat command? It's not the melt